# How to handle many different enemy types in one or a couple threads?

Tags: c++

I want to create a shooter, its only 2d and stuff, but I write it in C++ and want to have many different Enemies, where for example the one shoots every second, the other shoots every 3, and the last every 9 seconds, obviously it would be stupid to make a new thread per enemy type. But I learned that you can let a Thread sleep, and don't see a different way of making something do something every second/3seconds or 9secs. But I cant manage them all in one thread, so how do I do this?
Thanks already, I am pretty new to Programming.

Comment: Why would that be stupid?

Comment: You probably don't want to use sleep. You may want to compare timestamps or count intervals.

Comment: See [gamedev.se].

Answer (score 3):

You don't need threads just yet. When you say

> the one shoots every second, the other shoots every 3,

you seem to expect the code to sleep() or wait for some number of seconds.

That is not the right approach. What you want is a main loop with something like:

```
// called every 10 ms
void FixedUpdate()
{
    for(auto enemy: enemies)
    {
         enemy.Update();
    }
} 

void Enemy::Update()
{
    float now = time(); // replace with whatever timing mechanism your game uses
    if (mLastAction - now > 3.0f) // your enemy stores the last time it did something
    {
        PerformAction(); // the enemy has a function to perform actions
        mLastAction = now;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically I would look for something like a priority queue, and run the game in a single thread.

```
std::priority_queue< Objects >
```

would allow a single list of things to be done, and if the ordering is based on next-scheduled, then items can be added and removed dynamically to choose the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a `std::map` of events that need to happen with the key being the time at which they happen. Then your timer thread just calculates how long until the first event occurs, sleeps that long, and then fires off the first event.

The timer thread works like this:

1. Acquire the mutex that protects the event map.
2. See if it's time to fire the first event, if so, skip to step 6.
3. Calculate the time to the first event fires.
4. Block on the condition variable for the time calculated in step 3.
5. Go to step 2.
6. Take the first event out of the map.
7. Release the mutex that protects the event map.
8. Execute the event we removed from the map.
9. Go to step 1.

To queue a new event (which can be done while processing the previous event):

1. Acquire the mutex that protects the event map.
2. Add the event to the map, keyed by its execution time.
3. Signal the condition variable.
4. Release the mutex.

Comment: At the level where OP seems to be, I'd leave multithreading, events, murex, etc. out.